# "Can I do X" vs. "Can't I do X"

Tags: differences, questions, comparisons

Consider this scenarios:

> **A:** Can I do *X*?
>   **A:** Can't I do *X*?

In both the cases, the **B** replies with "Yes" to indicate **A** can do *X* and with "No" to indicate he cannot.

The 1<sup>st</sup> one seems to ask for permission while the 2<sup>nd</sup> one seems to imply a tone of indignation.

---

Consider another scenario:

> **A:** Can I not do *X*?
>   **A:** Can't I not do *X*?

Here, **B** replies with "Yes" to indicate **A** doesn't have to do *X* and with "No" to indicate **A** has to.

Here also, the difference is subtle: **A** seems to just ask for clarification or permission in the 1<sup>st</sup> and seems frustrated or even resigned in the 2<sup>nd</sup>.

---

My question is, what are the differences between the 2 then?

Comment: You've really hit the nail on the head with the overtones of indignation often present when the second variant is used. Intonation is controlling; a different tone with the second variant indicates the suggesting of a hitherto unstated and perhaps ingenious course of action - one that the addressee probably hasn't thought of; another tone, perhaps with an 'Oh!', indicates that the speaker has just had a eureka moment. The 'Can't' suggests asking for clarification of rules (rather than for overt permission), or feedback on the drawbacks about the suggested course of action X.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96447/15299

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615016/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that, when you add a negation to the verb Can, you don't really change the meaning of the question, which is to simply ask the permission.

So for instance, "Can I do X" is not different from "Can't I do X", so the same answer to either of these questions would have the same meaning.

However, when you add a negation to the verb Do, you change the meaning of the question, because now you're changing the action to which you wanted permission.

So "Can I do X" means something entirely different than "Can I not do X" and the same answer to these questions would therefore have entirely different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

in simple terms, open and closed answers, Can I do X? implies you want a quick yes or no. Whereas Can't I do X? implies you need further explanation on why you can't. The others are just double negatives as Henrique said.

Comment: Ah, but if you put a exclamation mark at the end like "Can't i do X!?" (although not thought of as 'good English') would imply you needed a quick yes or no almost overriding your passive stance!